# usb keyboard detected but wont work

Tags: usb, keyboard

As the title says, I have a USB keyboard setup on my tablet and it shows it in the input section, but it won't work.

It worked fine for a while but one day it just stopped working. I've tried 3 different keyboards.

The tablet is an Ellipsis 7. Up to date

Comment: faulty socket ?